# Could not bind properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, eclipselink

I've updated Spring Boot from version 1.5.6 to 2.0.0 and a lot of problems have started. One is the problem given in the subject.
I have a class with properties

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("eclipseLink")
public class EclipseLinkProperties { ... }
```

which I use in configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(EclipseLinkProperties.class)
public class WebDatasourceConfig { ... }
```

during compilation, he throws me away

```
2018-03-18 18:44:58.560  INFO 3528 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConversionServiceDeducer$Factory' of type [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConversionServiceDeducer$Factory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2018-03-18 18:44:58.575  WARN 3528 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webDatasourceConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eclipseLinkProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'eclipseLink-com.web.web.config.properties.EclipseLinkProperties': Could not bind properties to 'EclipseLinkProperties' : prefix=eclipseLink, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameException: Configuration property name 'eclipseLink' is not valid
```

It means

```
Configuration property name 'eclipseLink' is not valid
```

Before the Spring Boot update everything worked.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`eclipseLink` isn't a valid prefix. As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) kebab-case should be used rather than camelCase. So your prefix should be `eclipse-link` rather than `eclipseLink`.

Answer (score 7):

You can change:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("eclipseLink")
```

to:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("eclipselink")
```

You don't need to change properties file. This will avoid error. Spring will be able to find eclipseLink.* properties.

Answer (score 3):

Camel case is not supported in Spring boot 2.0. It would throw InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameException: Configuration property name '********' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue when a new config in one of the .yml files was not added in all .yml files(test.yml to be specific)

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue after upgrade spring boot version from 1.5 to 2.5 here it support kabab-case you can also change to **eclipse-link**