# I have upgraded Spring boot version from 1.5 to 2.1. But facing error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I found another post on Stackoverflow that was similar to my question. But It was saying "don't use Camel case in @ConfigurationProperties".

But, I'm not using Camel case. So that's why asking a new question.

I'm using below code in Spring Boot 2.1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(UMAAppProperties.class)
public class UMAAppConfig {

}
```

and

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app") //all properties are within the 'app' hierarchy
public class UMAAppProperties {

}
```

In application.yml, I'm writing:

```
app:      // This single line only. Nothing after that for app:
```

But, I'm getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

Error creating bean with name 'UMAAppConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 
'umaAppProperties'; 

nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: 
Error creating bean with name 'app-com.common.finding.abc.configuration.UMAAppProperties': Could not 
bind properties to 'UMAAppProperties' : prefix=app, ignoreInvalidFields=false, 
ignoreUnknownFields=true;
```

Any solution for that??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351104/could-not-bind-properties)

Comment: It was the link that I read before posting the question. But as I said in my own question that I'm not using Camel case. So that  doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I have seen something similar with logging levels, after upgrading Spring Boot didn't like that I declared zero actual loggers. I do believe that the problem eventually went away in the different patch versions, so are you on the latest Spring Boot 2.1 ? (2.1.12 at the time of writing)

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.6 version. Upgraded from 1.5 version

Comment: Well, there is no reason to stick to such an old version. Upgrade to the latest patch version to at least rule out that this is not some bug that has already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
As there is nothing under app: in application.yml  , then means we have to comment this line.